# Is it possible to default the `--force` parameter in `git branch --delete`?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

The `git branch --delete` (`git branch -d`) will show a warning, if it won't be reachable after deletion. The option `--force` (`-D`) will force the deletion.

Is it possible to configure git so that `git branch -d` behaves as `git branch -D`?

Comment: If you already have a solution, why would you want to change the default behavior of Git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've asked a specific question (is it possible to configure...), your commend doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible to configure *Git* this way.

You can, of course, make an *alias* (shell or Git alias) that invokes `git branch -D` and use that in place of `git branch -d`.  For instance, `git delbranch` or `delgitbranch` might be an alias for `git branch -D`.

Comment: Name it `branch-D`. Sorry, can't resist. :-)